# Alternative to grep function when searching

Tags: r

Relatively simple problem, but I'm thinking around in circles, and not reaching a solution. Essentially, I have `x=sample(1:30,20)` and I need to find the coordinates of each individual number. If I use grep, then I get where each number that has a 1 (including 10, 19, 21 etc.) is. I have a feeling there's an obscenely simple solution to this, but I can't think of it for some reason.

for example: if `x=c(2,3,1,10,12)`,

then

```
f(1,x)
[1] 3
```

and

```
f(3,x)
[1] 2
```

Note: I tried using `fixed = T`, but that did not help.

Comment: What's "*each individual number*"? What's your desired output? Please don't forget using `set.seed` when creating an example data

Comment: Edited appropriately.

Comment: So what `f(1,x)=3`, and `f(3,x)=2` means?

Comment: I'm looking for a function that I can use instead of grep to find elements of a vector. If I use grep, I would get `grep(1,x)` would give me `[1] 3 4 5`

Comment: Isn't this just `match(1,x)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail I"m guessing it won't work for dupes. `which` is also more efficient than `match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want `which`.

```
x <- c(2,3,1,10,12)
which(x==10)
[1] 4
```